# Django Attribute Error Str Object Homepage

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/, at the very top of the page, it says

```
AttributeError at /
'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

When I look at the command line, it's pointing to one of the files downloaded when I installed Django, `...\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py`.

Has anyone seen this before? Any suggestions?

**Edit**: This is what I see on command line:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Django version 3.0.7, using settings 'blog_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
"GET /admin/blog/post/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4528
"GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/css/changelists.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/js/jquery.init.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/js/core.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/js/actions.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/js/prepopulate.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/js/urlify.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
"GET /static/admin/img/tooltag-add.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 142, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 33, in get_queryset
    queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 81712
```

**Edit #2:**

The problem with this, based on the feedback from the answer that I marked as being the one that helped me with my problem, came from my `views.py file`.

Before (which was wrong):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Posttemplate_name = 'home.html'
```

After (which solved my problem):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

Comment: you need to share some code on that view, also the full error stacktrace

Comment: I edited my post, that's what I see on command line, does that help? I'm new to Django, so help me help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you defined the model class as a string in your view. Change it to model class. Like this:

```
from .models import YourModel

class SomeListView(ListView):
   model = YourModel  # <-- Here
```

Comment: Ah, I am new to Django (like 4 days into it) and wasn't sure what I was doing wrong. Thank you, that is what it was.